# load swf by UILoader as3 with different stage size

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

im trying to load external swf file with bigger size to my main swf. but i cant find any code for it. i manage to load the external swf but not the size i wanted any help pls...my main stage size is width 600 height 100.

```
import fl.containers.UILoader;

var MyLoader:UILoader = new UILoader();

MyLoader.autoLoad=true;
MyLoader.load();
MyLoader.source ="scene2.swf";
MyLoader.scaleContent = false;
MyLoader.move(0, 0);
MyLoader.width = 600;
MyLoader.height = 300;


addChild(MyLoader);



MyLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
function completeHandler(event:Event) {
trace("File loaded! " + MyLoader.bytesLoaded + " bytes");

}
```

Any help on what is going wrong would be greatly appreciated!!!!!!
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the loader width and height, finish the loading first and only then - in your completeHandler - add it to displaylist (addChild) and only after that change the size. Is it what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `MyLoader.scaleContent = false;` code.

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be no use of UILoader here. The write class is URLLoader and URLRequest. Like this:

```
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

import flash.net.URLLoader ;
import flash.net.URLRequest ; 

var mLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var mRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("scene2.swf");
mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);

mLoader.load(mRequest);


function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event)
{
        addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);
}
```

Comment: You do realize that you are using Loader (as you should) and not URLLoader?